# Do you have any eating requirements or allergies?

Tags: vocabulary

Eating requirements: 食物要求

Allergy: 过敏

But I came across another term which I can't seem to find. A waitress in China asked me if I had any eating requirements/allergies but she used a term that I think had 口 in it. I think it was 2 characters with 口 being either the first or second.

你有什么 口X 吗？

你有什么 X口 吗？

Have I misremembered or does such a term exist ?

Answer (score 6):

[戒口](https://cantoneseplus.com/word/194433) (restrict from eating)

> to not eat something for health reasons

For example, someone can't eat deep-fried food because of high blood pressure, or eat shellfish due to an allergy

*usually under a doctor's order*

有咳嗽時對生冷食物要戒口

糖尿病患者對甜品要戒口

我沒敏感症不用戒口

Comment: Thanks , can you add a few examples of it used in a sentence ?

Answer (score 5):

**忌口/口忌 - dietetic restrictions**; abstain from certain food due to illness or other health issues.

- 您有口忌嗎? - Do you have dietetic restrictions?
- 有. 因為忌口, 我得**避免**高鉀食品. - Yes, I do. Because of dietetic restrictions, I must **avoid** foods with very high potassium content.

**禁口/口禁 - dietetic prohibitions**; prohibited from certain food due to illness or other health issues.

- 醫生說什麽東西你要禁口? - Did the doctor prescribe dietetic prohibitions?
- 有, 醫生給我的口禁是**禁食海鮮**. - Yes, he did. He **prohibits me from eating seafood**.

Comment: 基本上中國對失業率有意見的人都被禁了口

Comment: @TangHo 此禁口(醫藥,飲食)非彼禁口(政治,語言). 就後者而言, 中國人早已被共產黨**禁聲**了, 無論是言語(之聲), 文字(之聲), 或行動(之聲).

Comment: Hi there, you all should be 禁言(ed) on all communist websites. :-) 禁言 actually includes spoken languages and written languages. But you can still 道路以目。

Answer (score 4):

I believe that's忌口/口忌

for 忌口， it's like you can't eat it for some objective reasons.

忌
--to be jealous; to envy; to hate
-- to envy
--(literary, or in compounds) to fear; to dread
**--to avoid**
--to abstain; to drop; to stop; to give up (a bad habit)
--to taboo; to prohibit
--taboo

Answer (score 2):

忌口, 戒口, 禁口, Which one?

忌口 is the one.

(1) It has been formally used in the Medicine Prescriptions by the professionals for a long time.

(2) 忌 means 禁忌(忌禁), 戒忌(忌戒), 忌讳(讳忌). The word 忌口 can substitude "戒口", "禁口", etc.

(3) It has less ambiguous (歧义) than 戒口 - 借口, 禁口 - 进口.